# Алгоритм в C# для логической игры

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм для подсчёта рекорда в C# для логической игры.
У меня есть игра, в которой нужно складывать картинку на время. Но я не могу придумать как организовать рекорд. Именно не время что бы как рекорд было, а очки.

Сейчас у меня первоначально задаётся значение, затем он делится на время уровня и умножается на кол-во прямоугольников.

P.S кол-во прямоугольников у меня: 4,9,16,25; время уровня устанавливает сам пользователь в настройках, Первоначальные очки я устанавливаю сам(по умолчанию поставил 1200)

```
private string calculatePlayerScore(int record)
{
    int playerScore = record / timerValue * LengthSides; // 1200 * на минуты в настройках * кол-во прямоугольников
    return playerScore.ToString();
}
```

Но хотелось бы как-то по оригинальному сделать. Я не знаю просто какие есть алгоритмы для таких игр

Comment: Как он устанавливает время уровня? Успеет собрать или проиграет? Можно добавить бонусы. Можно добавить количество действий перестановок картинок (но результат будет зависить от везения). Отмена действий и подсказки отнимают очки. Можно добавить бонусы за быстое собирание нескольких фрагментов.

Comment: @codename0082016 Время за которое он собирается собрать картинку и кол-во прямоугольников на сколько разделяется картинка.